# Does Interfaces (or abstract classes) make sense if there is only one implementation?

Tags: interface, abstract-class

As the title says: Does it make sense to use interfaces (or abstract classes) even if there is only one implementation?

I feel that it might add clarity, but on the other hand it's obviously additional code and another indirection.